# Custom dialog in custom class returns boolean value

Tags: android, class, dialog

I have searched for the answer and dont find it, so please help me :)

I have a custom class:

```
public class CustomClass {

    private final Context ctx;
    public CustomClass(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public boolean setDialog(int head, int text) {
        final boolean value;

        final Dialog d = new Dialog(ctx);
        d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.custom2_dialog);

        TextView txtHead = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.custom2_txtHead);
        txtHead.setText(ctx.getResources().getString(head));
        TextView txtText = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.custom2_txtText);
        txtText.setText(ctx.getResources().getString(text));

        Button btnOK = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.custom2_btnOK);
        btnOK.setText("OK");
        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                value = true;
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button btnNO = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.custom2_btnNO);
        btnNO.setText("NO");
        btnNO.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                value = false;
                d.dismiss();
            }
        });

        d.show();

        return value;
    }
}
```

You can see that i have a custom dialog created in my custom class because i dont want to create in every activity a dialog. Now when i use it in an Activity:

```
CustomClass cC = new CustomClass(this);
if(cC.setDialog(R.string.head, R.string.text)) {
    // user checked OK
} else {
   // user checked NO
}
```

How to know if user checked OK or NO, because the return true, false value dont work in custom class, the dialog wont wait before the user clicks, it automatic return a value.

Comment: Simple Buddy, Instead of Creating Custom Class for Dialog use `Application` Class define the same method in that but for method `setDialog()` return `Void` and declare variable `boolean value` globally, now you can get anywhere what user select.

Comment: The Best thing about Application class is you don't need to pass Context of Current Activity at everytime when you want to show Dialog..

Comment: You cannot get the return value synchronously. You will have to use a listener

Comment: @user370305 i dont know what you mean return void, when i change the mothod from boolean to void, i cant return anything, have you an example?

Comment: You don't need to return value. Read carefully my first comment..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your question. 
First of all, if you are creating the Custom dialog then you have to to extend the **Dialog** class to read the response and implement the **OnClickListener**.

```
class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener
{
  // some code
public CustomizeDialog(Activity activity, String title, String msg, int i, Typeface typeface) 
    {
        super(activity);        
        this.activity = activity;
        intFlag = i;
        setContentView(R.layout.relative);
        dialogButtonYes = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCustomDialogYes);
        dialogButtonNo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCustomDialogNo);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCustomTitle);
        this.msg = msg;
        dialogButtonNo.setOnClickListener(this);
        dialogButtonYes.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == dialogButtonYes)
        {
            Intent intent =new Intent(activity, CallForOne.class);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            dismiss();
        }
        else
            dismiss();
    }
    else if(intFlag == 2)
    {
        if (v == dialogButtonYes)
        {
            Intent intent =new Intent(activity, CallMe.class);
            activity.startActivity(intent);
            dismiss();
        }
        else
            dismiss();
}
```

And the **relative.xml** file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCustomTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textViewCustomTitle"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="5.0dip" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCustomDialogYes"
        style="@style/styleNormalButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="@string/yes" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonCustomDialogNo"
        style="@style/styleNormalButton"
        android:layout_width="0.0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:text="@string/no" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the main class

```
    class Main implements OnClickListener
    {
    onCreate()
    {
    //your code
    }

    public void on click()
    {
    customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(CustomDialogExample.this,getString(R.string.title_for_one),getString(R.string.msg_for_one),1,"String");
    customizeDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any other solution?, I dont want to create another class for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem here, then I found one solution, to open an **Activity** from button click in a **custom dialog**. But you can use this logic for another actions too.

My custom method:

```
public class Extension extends Activity{

  public void showDialogConfirma(Activity localActivity, Class destActivity, String titulo, String mensagem){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(localActivity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_um_btn);

    TextView textTitulo = dialog.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    textTitulo.setText(titulo);

    Button btnOk = dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            // here I can open any activity from any class
            localActivity.startActivity(new Intent(localActivity, destActivity));
        }
    });

    dialog.show();

  }
}
```

You call this method like this:

```
Extension extension = new Extension();
// here you gonna pass your parameters to your Dialog on create it
// on my case the activity that I want open
extension.showDialogConfirma(ThisActivity.this, DestActivity.class, titulo, mensagem);
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all the comment from @user370305 is the way to do it right. There can be other ways no doubts about that.

The problem you are facing is because when you are calling a method of custom class

```
   if(cC.setDialog(R.string.head, R.string.text));
```

you are getting the value even though nothing has been clicked

```
 return value;
```

as false which is the default value set when you are declaring

```
final boolean value;
```

Instead you should listen for the Cancel and Ok clicks

Comment: Can you give me a example? I thought that there was a simple solution.

Comment: That is not a answer, he knows that his code is wrong, you dont need to tell him again.